# Convert Exponential to Varchar in Netezza

Tags: type-conversion, varchar, netezza, exponential

I have this `12241089001` value read as `1.2241089001E10` in Netezza. Actually the data type is Varchar. How can this read as exponential?
When I convert `1.2241089001E10` into Varchar, it's only cut the `E10`. Example : `1.2241089001`. How to save this value into `12241089001`?

Comment: On second read I'm not entirely sure what type you are trying to cast to which other type. Can you show an example of the conversion code you are trying that isn't doing what you want? And be clear on the original day at type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct CAST from VARCHAR to FLOAT or NUMERIC should do the trick.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select '1.2241089001E10'::float;
  ?COLUMN?
-------------
 12241089001
(1 row)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select '1.2241089001E10'::numeric(38,10);
        ?COLUMN?
------------------------
 12241089001.0000000000
(1 row)
```